# HTML optgroup multiple select without control key

Tags: javascript, html

```
        <tr>
            <td><label for="year">YEARS</label></td>
            <td>
                <select name="test" id="years" multiple="multiple" size="10">
                    <optgroup label="CHILD/TEEN">
                        <option value="zero">0</option>
                        <option value="one">10</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="ADULT">
                        <option value="two" selected>20</option>
                        <option value="three">30</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="ADULTADULT">
                        <option value="four">40</option>
                        <option value="five">50</option>
                        <option value="upsix">60</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I tried to select multiple. But I can't select multiple without 'control' key.

I must use the optgroup :(

HOW I SOLVE THIS PROBLEM?

Comment: Works fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/oy7d1yt3/

Comment: @adeneo: You still have to use the CTRL key to select multiple in your example.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat - oh okay, that's what "control key" means? That's how it works, changing that would be horrible UX.

Comment: @차민재: Why do you want to _not_ use the CTRL key? This is just how the browser works, and most users will understand that.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah, I still using the CTRL key

Comment: And you should continue to do so

Comment: @Whothehellisthat Using the CTRL key is just troublesome.

Comment: I understand this but, other users maybe can't understand how it works.

Comment: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html
Multiple Selection

Use this one

Comment: You should just explain it near the select box. If you want things to work like a multiple-select box, then they'll work like that. If you want them to work like checkboxes (where you can just click on individual items and they'll be selected), and add headings for each group of checkboxes, that would work without using CTRL.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat hmmm yes. I will consider your opinion thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use below pure Javacript:

```
function init() {
  if (arguments.callee.done) return;
  arguments.callee.done = true;
  if (khtmltimer) clearInterval(khtmltimer);
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].hasAttribute('multiple')) {
      s[i].onclick = updateSelect;
    }
  }
}
function updateSelect(e) {
  var opts = this.getElementsByTagName('option'), t, o;
  if (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    t = e.target;
  }
  else if (window.event) {
    window.event.returnValue = false;
    t = window.event.srcElement;
  }
  else return;
  t = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
  if (t.getAttribute('class') == 'selected') t.removeAttribute('class');
  else t.setAttribute('class', 'selected');
  for (var i = 0, j = opts.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (opts[i].hasAttribute('class')) opts[i].selected = true;
    else opts[i].selected = false;
  }
}

if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
    document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\\/script>");
    var script = document.getElementById('__ie_onload');
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
            init();
        }
    };
/*@end @*/
if (/KHTML/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    var khtmltimer = setInterval(function() {
        if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
            init();
        }
    }, 10);
}
window.onload = init;
```

refer this **Updated** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/dd0v8L4L/)

Hope it helps you

Thanks

Comment: While this works, I highly suggest _not_ messing with how form items work, like that. People will get confused, and it's just a bad idea to show something that looks like a select box, but is not a select box.

Comment: Options don't consistenly fire mouse events, so in fact this doesn't work in all browsers (not firefox I believe).

Comment: thx your comment. But I don't know how link javascript in sublime text

Comment: @차민재  I used JQuery for this

Comment: Seems it's the other way around, only Firefox fully supports mouse events on options. It does seem to work in latest Chrome, but I suspect it won't work in IE/Safari, can't be bothered to test it, I just know that mouse events on an option is always a bad idea.

Comment: @SunilKumar a... thx but I can not use JQuery yet. It is similar with sublime text?

Comment: Why this doesn't work when I put document.getElementsByID('years'); instead fo getByTagName ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use checkboxes for forms where mutliple options can be selected at once, in this case. They do not need the user to hold CTRL, and will be understood by everyone.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>CHILD/TEEN</legend>
  <input id="child-0" type="checkbox" /><label for="child-0">0</label>
  <input id="child-10" type="checkbox" /><label for="child-10">10</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>ADULT</legend>
  <input id="adult-20" type="checkbox" /><label for="adult-20">20</label>
  <input id="adult-30" type="checkbox" /><label for="adult-30">20</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>ADULTADULT</legend>
  <input id="adult-40" type="checkbox" /><label for="adult-40">40</label>
  <input id="adult-50" type="checkbox" /><label for="adult-50">50</label>
  <input id="adult-60" type="checkbox" /><label for="adult-60">60</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: thx. But, I should use the select-optgroup. thx your comment :)